# Parsing HTML with Beautiful Soup to get link after href

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

This is a result of a `find_all('a')` (it's very long):

```
</a>, <a class="btn text-default text-dark clear_filters pull-right group-ib" href="#" id="export_dialog_close" title="Cancel"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span><span>Cancel</span></a>, <a href="/ais/index/port_moves/all/include_anchs:no/ship_type:7/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9/in_transit:no/time_interval:1474948800.0_1475035200.00/per_page:50/portname:NOVOROSSIYSK/cb:6651/move_type:1/sort:SHIPNAME/direction:asc">Vessel Name</a>, <a href="/ais/index/port_moves/all/include_anchs:no/ship_type:7/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9/in_transit:no/time_interval:1474948800.0_1475035200.00/per_page:50/portname:NOVOROSSIYSK/cb:6651/move_type:1/sort:TIMESTAMP_UTC/direction:asc">Timestamp</a>, <a href="/ais/index/port_moves/all/include_anchs:no/ship_type:7/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9/in_transit:no/time_interval:1474948800.0_1475035200.00/per_page:50/portname:NOVOROSSIYSK/cb:6651/move_type:1/sort:PORT_NAME/direction:asc">Port</a>, <a href="/ais/index/port_moves/all/include_anchs:no/ship_type:7/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9/in_transit:no/time_interval:1474948800.0_1475035200.00/per_page:50/portname:NOVOROSSIYSK/cb:6651/move_type:1/sort:MOVE_TYPE_NAME/direction:asc">Port Call type</a>, <a href="/ais/index/port_moves/all/include_anchs:no/ship_type:7/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9/in_transit:no/time_interval:1474948800.0_1475035200.00/per_page:50/portname:NOVOROSSIYSK/cb:6651/move_type:1/sort:ELAPSED/direction:asc">Time Elapsed</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:465271/imo:9495595/mmsi:373571000/vessel:SIDER%20LUCK/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: SIDER LUCK">SIDER LUCK</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ports/767/port_name:NOVOROSSIYSK/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: NOVOROSSIYSK">NOVOROSSIYSK</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ports/163/port_name:MILAZZO/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: MILAZZO">MILAZZO</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:288753/imo:9389693/mmsi:249474000/vessel:OOCL%20ISTANBUL/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: OOCL ISTANBUL">OOCL ISTANBUL</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ports/767/port_name:NOVOROSSIYSK/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: NOVOROSSIYSK">NOVOROSSIYSK</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ports/17436/port_name:AMBARLI/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: AMBARLI">AMBARLI</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:754480/imo:9045613/mmsi:636014098/vessel:TK%20ROTTERDAM/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: TK ROTTERDAM">TK ROTTERDAM</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ports/767/port_name:NOVOROSSIYSK/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: NOVOROSSIYSK">NOVOROSSIYSK</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ports/3504/port_name:DILISKELESI/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: DILISKELESI">DILISKELESI</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:412277/imo:9039585/mmsi:353430000/vessel:SEA%20AEOLIS/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: SEA AEOLIS">SEA AEOLIS</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ports/767/port_name:NOVOROSSIYSK/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: NOVOROSSIYSK">NOVOROSSIYSK</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ports/1/port_name:PIRAEUS/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: PIRAEUS">PIRAEUS</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:346713/imo:7614599/mmsi:273327300/vessel:SOLIDAT/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: SOLIDAT">SOLIDAT</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ports/767/port_name:NOVOROSSIYSK/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: NOVOROSSIYSK">NOVOROSSIYSK</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ports/883/port_name:SEVASTOPOL/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: SEVASTOPOL">SEVASTOPOL</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:752974/imo:9195298/mmsi:636011072/vessel:OCEANPRINCESS/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: OCEANPRINCESS">OCEANPRINCESS</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ports/767/port_name:NOVOROSSIYSK/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: NOVOROSSIYSK">NOVOROSSIYSK</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ports/21780/port_name:EREGLI/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: EREGLI">EREGLI</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:201260/imo:9385075/mmsi:235102768/vessel:EMERALD%20BAY/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: EMERALD BAY">EMERALD BAY</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ports/767/port_name:NOVOROSSIYSK/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: NOVOROSSIYSK">NOVOROSSIYSK</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ports/767/port_name:NOVOROSSIYSK/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: NOVOROSSIYSK">NOVOROSSIYSK</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:418956/imo:9102746/mmsi:356579000/vessel:MSC%20DON%20GIOVANNI/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: MSC DON GIOVANNI">MSC DON GIOVANNI</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ports/767/port_name:NOVOROSSIYSK/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: NOVOROSSIYSK">NOVOROSSIYSK</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ports/67/port_name:CONSTANTA/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: CONSTANTA">CONSTANTA</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:748395/imo:9460734/mmsi:622121422/vessel:WADI%20SAFAGA/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: WADI SAFAGA">WADI SAFAGA</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ports/767/port_name:NOVOROSSIYSK/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: NOVOROSSIYSK">NOVOROSSIYSK</a>, <a href="/en/ais/details/ports/997/port_name:DAMIETTA/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9" title="View details for: DAMIETTA">DAMIETTA</a>
```

I want to pull out the strings that start with `/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:` such as:

```
<a href="/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:465271/imo:9495595/mmsi:373571000/vessel:SIDER%20LUCK/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9"
```

I was able to copy these examples ([Find specific link w/ beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732694/find-specific-link-w-beautifulsoup) or [How to get Beautiful Soup to get link from href and class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611592/how-to-get-beautiful-soup-to-get-link-from-href-and-class)) but I would rather not use regex.

So far I have:

```
for i in ase: #ase is where the html is sotred
    print(i.get('href')) #prints everysingle href.
```

In short, my question is how do I only keep the `href`'s that have the string I'm interested in without using regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@elethan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39901685/771848) is not the best one. It would **find you all the links and only then filter them out**. Why don't we just *get the links we needed straight with no extra filtering* - `BeautifulSoup` is very capable of that:

```
prefix = "/en/ais/details/ships/shipid"
[a["href"] for a in soup("a", href=lambda x: x and x.startswith(prefix))]
```

Or, instead of a [function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function), you can pass a [regular expression pattern](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) to check if a string "starts with" a desired sub-string:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"^/en/ais/details/ships/shipid")
[a["href"] for a in soup("a", href=pattern)]
```

`^` here denotes the beginning of a string.

Or, we can even use a CSS selector:

```
[a["href"] for a in soup.select('a[href^="/en/ais/details/ships/shipid"]')]
```

`^=` is a "starts-with" selector.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following list comprehension:

```
[h.get('href') for h in ase if 'string' in h.get('href', '')]
```

This will give you a list containing only the links that contain the substring `'string'`.

## Update:

As **@PadraicCunningham** pointed out in the comments, `'string' in h.get('href')` (which was part of my original answer) will raise a `TypeError` if `h` does not have a key `'href'` - not likely since `h` will be a representation of an `<a>` tag, but also certainly a non-trivial possibility. To allow for this possibility, you can simply pass to `.get()` a default argument of `''` to be returned instead of `None` when a key does not exist.

Also, I have made no claims that my solution is the best; it is likely not particularly efficient or elegant. However, from my understanding of the OPs question, this solution will work, is minimal, and is easy to understand.

Comment: wait, can you really do `element.get('attr')` instead of `element.attrs.get('attr')`?! that looks so much nicer! e: checked docs, and it's mentioned right there. don't know how i missed that for so long.

Comment: @n1c9 Nice, isn't it? There is a reason it is called "Beautiful"Soup, haha.

Comment: `'string'  in None -> error`, you only need to use .get if you expect a href to not exist on the node you are calling it on, considering you can set `href=True` and also use a  css selector, a regex etc.. there is no reason to ever need to resort to  using .get, especially calling it twice. Also a substring being in a string is not the same as a string starting with a substring.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks for pointing out the possibility of `.get()` returning `None` and raising an error here. This was a big oversight on my part, and I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would still advice you to use regex, as it is more concise and saves you another loop over the list.

```
import re
find_all('a', href=re.compile("/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:"))
```

In the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) you find a similar solution to this.